# Unable to run wubi on XP

Tags: installation, wubi

I am trying to run wubi on Windows XP Professional 5.1 (Build 2600.xpsp_sp3_gdr.120821-1629: SP 3)

I have Administrator rights

I downloaded wubi from [here](http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu-releases//quantal/wubi.exe)

I have installed Python 3.2 and my PATH is set as

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.5\miktex\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Perl\bin\;C:\Program Files\Hummingbird\Connectivity\8.00\Accessories\;C:\Program Files\Hummingbird\Connectivity\8.00\NFSClient;C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\PalmOSCygwin\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

When I run wubi.exe I get the Windows security warning, when I ask to Run, there is a pause, a beep and nothing else happens.

Comment: Hey, Is there no output at all? Are you connected to the internet on the windows XP machine? And as far as I can see I don't see a link to your Python 3.* installation in your path.

Comment: I have worked out that in %TEMP% a folder is created: Temp\py%%%.tmp   This has a pyrun.exe and a pylauncher.exe, neither will run (The instruction at 0x77c460cb referenced memory at 0x00000000.  The memory could not be read.) There are two .pyo files and the python23.dll in the folder and some sub-folders.  In one of the sub-folders there is the cyqwin.dll and so I have removed cyqwin from my PATH, but still no luck

Comment: Do you have any Python environment variables set? i.e. check this https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/365501/comments/20

Comment: it is possible to install different version of python on the same machine. please try out version 2.7 and tell me the result.

Comment: There were/are no (obvious) Python environment variables set (such as PYTHONCASEOK).  I unistalled Python 3.3 and installed Python 2.7.3.  Executing python.exe -E main.pyo returns "RuntimeError:  Bad magic number in .pyc file"

Comment: This question has evolved into a new one here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/256899/how-safe-is-hacking-wubi

Comment: @user130691 Wubi uses python 2.3, but you don't need to install python. Did you try it inbetween uninstalling 3.3 and before you installed 2.7.3?

Comment: yes I did - but I also had cygwin installed and I wondered if this could have caused an issue